# Set more than one cronjob with php for raspberry pi

Tags: php, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I want to set several cronjobs for my raspberry pi with php. The code works fine if there is only one cronjob to insert like this:

```
$hour = $_GET["hour"];
$mins = $_GET["mins"];



exec('echo "'.$mins.' '.$hour.' * * * sudo gpio -g write 18 1" | crontab -');
```

If i want to add another one directly after the first one, for example:

```
exec('echo "'.$mins.' '.$hour.' * * * sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```

It will just execute the last one.. how can I set more than one cronjob?

Thank you!

Comment: reading from `-` (stdin) REPLACES the original crontab with whatever you're feeding in. it doesn't edit/append, it just replaces.

Comment: Thanks. It will work like that (seperated by ";") exec('echo "'.$mins.' '.$hour.' * * * sudo gpio -g write 18 1; sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will work seperated by a ";"

```
exec('echo "'.$mins.' '.$hour.' * * * sudo gpio -g write 18 1; sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -');
```